# Unable to downloading Zip file from Ajax byte reponse(converting it to Blob) in js

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am having a scenario where i have to create/download a zip file that is created using multiple files from url's in a jsp(No servlet imlementation) which is called using **only ajax call** as i need to implement progress bar (not accurate just for a view) in js file .

I have tried creating a zipoutputstream in jsp and it is perfectly going well using

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

ZipOutputStream  zos = new ZipOutputStream( bos );
```

finally sending the  data in byte stream

```
response.getOutputStream().write(**bos.toByteArray()**);                   
                    response.flushBuffer();
```

In Js file i have tried the follwing code

```
var $download_status = $.ajax({

                    "url" :  jsp url where zip is created
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "html",
                    contentType: "application/zip",                    

                    success : function (data) {
                       console.log(data.length);
                        //the data is having the exact size as the zos 
                        var blob = new Blob([data]);
                       // the blob file is getting 2X size 
                        var link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        link.download = seiesName+".zip";
                        link.click();
                    },
                });
```

When i downloaded the file i am getting corrupted file whose size is almost 2x to the original file .

Please any one help me with this ...

Thanks in advance...

Regards,
Vamc.

Comment: Just a note: `contentType: "application/zip",` sets the data type of the data you are _sending_ to the server. `dataType: "html"` sets the type of data jQuery is expecting to _receive_ from the server. Not 100% sure if telling it to expect HTML will corrupt things, but it certainly isn't going to be helpful.